# How to detect un-ability to load font from google web fonts

Tags: webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm loading google web fonts to display some text strings.

What I want to do is, if in any case if Google web fonts fails to load (maybe a time out or network issue etc etc), I want to display an image instead of falling to the font family stack.

So is there a way to detect that Google web fonts has been successfully loaded or not; so that I can implement something like

```
if (Google webfont loads successfully) {
    //display the string using that font
} else {
    //display an image instead
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webfont load request will yield class attributes on the HTML node of your page. Using the [Google Webfont Loader](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader) (which I'm assuming the Google type service uses, along with Typekit), the following classes will indicate status:

1. wf-inactive (the one you're looking for)
2. wf-loading
3. wf-active

In addition, you'll have font-specific classes, such as wf-myfont-active.